# Setting curl proxy options in R

Tags: r, curl

I'm running R on a Windows machine behind a corporate proxy. When running R 3.3.2 and version 2.3 of the curl package, this works:

```
curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://google.com")
```

Also note the following:

```
> curl::curl_options(filter = "sslcert")
    sslcert sslcerttype 
      10025       10086
```

However, this is what happens when running R 3.4.1 and curl 2.8:

```
> curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://google.com")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://google.com") : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Note:

```
> curl::curl_options(filter = "sslcert")
    proxy_sslcert proxy_sslcerttype           sslcert       sslcerttype 
            10254             10255             10025             10086
```

I gather from the curl source code that these two new options were added in between these two versions.

Since this is the only relevant difference that I can find, my hunch is that curl is looking for the proxy_sslcert in the wrong path. But I can't figure out how to change that variable, nor what I should change it to. Also, what are the numbers shown (10254, etc)?

I don't actually need to use `curl` specifically, but a lot of other packages rely on it, e.g.

```
> httr::GET("https://google.com")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Comment: Try setting `verbose = TRUE`, that might give you some more clues.